# Can we build java application through build plagin of maven without installing local JDK

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, maven-plugin

Can we build java web app through build plagin of maven without installing local JDK.

As we all know that we have plugins in POM.xml and maven is using them for different steps, So my question is that is it possible that I write java code with POM.xml file and then add build/compile plugins to that POM.xml file and then compile this code only through maven plugin instead of installing jdk locally ?

If this is not possible then what is purpose of adding build and compile plugins to POM file ?

Comment: You seemed to misunderstand the intention of maven-compiler-plugin ? And no it's not possible to build a java app without using JDK...installed because Maven it self as well as your app need JDK to be able to compile java code into class files... Can you also more detail describe what your problem is ? Because to be honest it's confusing?

Comment: @khmarbaise the only confusion I have is that when locally installed JDK is used to compile and build java code then why do we use the maven build and compile plugins in our POM.xml file? This is the thing which I want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, as @khmarbaise mentioned, is no. Building java applications without jdk is not an option.

Maven plugins solve issues, depending on the plugin they may move things, generate code or do similar things to make the real build possible. They do not in any way replace a jdk tho.

Comment: Bjorn my question is still there that as you have stated that plugins "generate code or do similar things to make the real build possible" then why it is not possible to build and compile code without JDK because JDK is also doing the same thing.

Comment: the difference is, that the jdk is creating executable code - the plugins are creating files that are not by themself executable usually.

Comment: Buttner are these files .class files ? if not then what type of files are these?

Comment: For example I generate css files with a plugin, an exe with another one and text files with a third - not usually class files.